# PHP - Can't post an image to my restful service

Tags: php, rest, curl

I'm trying to use cURL to post an image to my REStful service's picture upload method.

The restful service requires a request in the following format: -

```
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Content-Length: 782
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary5dQ1ta4rvOvWtjff
```

It also uses an authorization token string.

Here's my PHP code: -

$_FILES['file'] was passed to this as $data, as a sidenote.

```
move_uploaded_file($data["tmp_name"], "../uploaded_files/images/".$data["name"]);
$data_string = "@".realpath("../uploaded_files/images/".$data["name"]).";type=image/png";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$boundary = md5(date('U'));
$http_headers = array(
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$_SESSION['Auth'],
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch',
    'Content-Length: '.$data['size'],
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary"."\r\n"              
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

To the best of my knowledge, this should match and work, however it doesn't. When I include the Content-Length (as it's required and will generate a 411 code otherwise), the server freezes up and then after a long time it generates this error:-

```
SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 0
```

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong? I'm able to successfully Post JSON and other content types using the above code, it seems to just be specific for me trying to POST an image that way.

Edit: I've been told the @ method for file upload is deprecated, so I've adjust my code to this: -

```
$path = realpath("../upload_files/images/".$data["name"]);
$cfile = curl_file_create($path, 'image/png','file_upload');
$data_string = array('file_upload' => $cfile);
```

However now it generates a 400 status code for "bad request". Am I using this method wrong, or is there something I'm missing? I've tried the Object oriented version below as well, but it generated the same issue.

```
$cfile = new CURLFile($path,'image/png','file_upload');
```

Comment: @filename API for file uploading is deprecated. You may use the CURLFile class instead.

Comment: I've adjusted the code to use that class, however now I get a code 400 bad request.

Comment: Debug the CURL, see what header/body is sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the issue here.

The restful service that my cURL is attempting to connect to requires the Content Disposition headers to be set, something that cURL intentionally ignores, as it sets its own boundaries.

This being the case, it's impossible to accomplish what I'm trying to do using this API's method as is, with PHP.

That is, unless anyone knows of a different php libraries where setting content dispositions is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is related to `Content-Type` of your request. Judging the given format it should be set to `multipart/form-data`, i.e. the sent data should be encoded as `multipart/form-data`. According to [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), in order to set `Content-Type` header to `multipart/form-data` you have to set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option to an `array` (not URL-encoded string as in your code). In this case the data will be encoded as `multipart/form-data` automatically.

So your code should look like this:

```
move_uploaded_file($data["tmp_name"], "../uploaded_files/images/".$data["name"]);
$path = realpath("../uploaded_files/images/".$data["name"]);
$data = array('file' => "@$path;type=image/png");
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
...
```

*BTW:* `@` prefix is only deprecated since PHP 5.5.0.

Comment: The content type IS set to the multipart/form-data though. I've set the POSTfield variable ($data_string) to an array, however now the service denies it with a code 400: Bad Request, which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I've discovered the issue, it's a combination of how cURL is written, and how the method this RESTful API's service is written to interpret the headers being requested. I've posted an answer detailing this.